# Error installing a dependency .deb package: depends on python (>= 2.7~); however: Package python is not installed

Tags: python, xubuntu, deb

I am trying to install PyRenamer.deb in Xubuntu 22.04: https://launchpad.net/pyrenamer

Pyrenamer is written in Python2, and has several .deb package dependencies, which I have downloaded and collected.

I have installed Python2, and I have set up Python Alternatives correctly, so that:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.18
$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.18
$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.4
```

So, when I try installing one of the dependency .deb packages:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i python-gobject-2_2.28.6-12ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

This error message occurs:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gobject-2:
 python-gobject-2 depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-gobject-2 depends on python (>= 2.7~); however:
  Package python is not installed.
```

Why would I be getting this error message, when Python 2.7.18 is installed, and is set up correctly for python to function? I have tried and tried, and I have searched online for relevant help, but I can't find a solution to this problem.

```
$ dpkg -l '*python*'

||/ Name                          Version                  Architecture Description
+++-=============================-========================-============-================================================================================
ii  hexchat-python3:amd64         2.16.0-4build1           amd64        Python 3 plugin for HexChat
ii  libpython-all-dbg:amd64       2.7.18-3                 amd64        package depending on all supported Python2 debugging packages
ii  libpython-all-dev:amd64       2.7.18-3                 amd64        package depending on all supported Python2 development packages
un  libpython-dbg                 <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  libpython-dev                 <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  libpython-stdlib              <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
ii  libpython2-dbg:amd64          2.7.18-3                 amd64        debug build of the Python2 interpreter (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2-dev:amd64          2.7.18-3                 amd64        header files and a static library for Python2
ii  libpython2-stdlib:amd64       2.7.18-3                 amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2)
ii  libpython2.7:amd64            2.7.18-13ubuntu1         amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-dbg:amd64        2.7.18-13ubuntu1         amd64        Debug Build of the Python Interpreter (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-dev:amd64        2.7.18-13ubuntu1         amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64    2.7.18-13ubuntu1         amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64     2.7.18-13ubuntu1         amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-testsuite        2.7.18-13ubuntu1         all          Testsuite for the Python standard library (v2.7)
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64       3.10.4-0ubuntu2          amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  libpython3.10:amd64           3.10.4-3                 amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.10)
ii  libpython3.10-minimal:amd64   3.10.4-3                 amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.10)
ii  libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64    3.10.4-3                 amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.10)
un  libpython3.4-minimal          <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  libpython3.5-minimal          <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  libpython3.8-stdlib           <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  python                        <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
un  python-4suite                 <none>                   <none>       (no description available)
ii  python-all                    2.7.18-3                 amd64        package depending on all supported Python2 runtime versions
ii  python-all-dbg                2.7.18-3                 amd64        package depending on all supported Python2 debugging packages
ii  python-all-dev                2.7.18-3                 amd64        package depending on all supported Python2 development packages
un  python-apport
```

I followed instructions on this webpage:

https://linuxconfig.org/install-python-2-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

to install python2, with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python2
```

I followed instructions on this webpage:

https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-python-version-switch-manager

to set up alternatives for python:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3   2         manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Comment: How did you install Python 2?  Dpkg only knows about packages it installs.

Comment: “Python alternatives” means Python wasn’t installed using (only) a package, since the Ubuntu Python packages don’t use alternatives. The “correct” fix would have been to install `python-is-python2`, but that’s no longer available in 22.04.

Comment: dpkg - l | grep python | sort
dpkg: error: need an action option

Comment: It should be `dpkg -l '*python*'`.